# Navigation stuck to rootviewcontroller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I am creating an app with a `pagecontrol` with three views each view contains a button which on click calls a `xib` but the problem is the `xib` loads in the view which looks very bad as the view is in the centre on main screen i want the xib to appear as a whole page so i created a method in app delegate and then called it from the buttons in the view and now xib loads separately but when i comeback to the view and call the same function it repeats the main page again and again .. 
i know its looong question but i would appreciate any effort as i am a beginner .... thanks 
code in app delegate is

```
-(void)specify
{
    ResultViewController *res = [[ResultViewController alloc]init];
    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.3;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
    [self.window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];       
    [self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:res animated:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't get it exactly, but i think u should put XIB programmatically.

self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

Is it okay ?